# Asp .NET Making a value Check on a drop down list from a nother drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to force the user to change the selection of the first drop down list IF he/she selected a particular value in the second drop down list.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGxP" runat="server" CssClass="stdDropdownSmall" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGxP_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

<
  else
  {
        
    } 
The above is the first drop down list where the user should select value from  "ddlGxP"

The following is the second drop down list where I need to make the check when the user make a selection, I have to check on the first drop down.

```
<div class="divStandard">
    <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" CssClass="stdLabel">nalized Method <span class="mandatory"> *</span></asp:Label>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFinalizedMethod" runat="server" CssClass="stdDropdown" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvFinalizedMethod" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlFinalizedMethod" InitialValue="0" OnServerValidate="cvFinalizedMethod_ServerValidate"
        CssClass="RequiredFieldError" ErrorMessage=" ! Please select another GxP Standard"  />
    } else {
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFinalizedMethodDisabled" runat="server" CssClass="stdTextboxSmallDisabled" Enabled="false" />
    } 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't have enough reputation so here is my comment.

i just want to clarify the problem in basic terms.
your design view consists of two dropdownlists.
you make a selection on dropdownlist1, its selectedindexchanged is triggered performing some sort of action.

you now make a selection on dropdownlist2, its selectedindexchanged is triggered and performs some sort of manipulation on dropdownlist1, either changing its contents or selected value;

SORRY FOR THE WAIT, I MADE SOME SIMPLE ERRORS DUE TO FORGETTING SOME THINGS;

The ANSWER!!!!

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></div>
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddl2_selectindexchange">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</form>
</body>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        List<string> str = new List<string>();
        str.Add("red");
        str.Add("blue");
        str.Add("black");

        List<string> str2 = new List<string>();
        str2.Add("red");
        str2.Add("blue");
        str2.Add("black");

        DropDownList1.DataSource = null;
        DropDownList1.DataSource = str;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList2.DataSource = null;
        DropDownList2.DataSource = str2;
        DropDownList2.DataBind();

    }
}

protected void ddl2_selectindexchange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl = sender as DropDownList;

    ListItem li = new ListItem();
    li = ddl.SelectedItem;
    string s = li.Text;
    Label1.Text = s;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I tried to find examples, but no luck. Can you help me?

Comment: so are the values for ddls dynamically set at run time on page load

Comment: Yes, the values are loaded at run time

Comment: example: List<string> str = new List<string>(); str.Add("RED"); str.Add("blue"); ddl1.DataSource = null; ddl1.DataSource = str; ddl1.DataBind();

Comment: what are you trying to do? change the selected index, or the ddl text values;

Comment: What try to do is the following: if (DDL_1 == str.value) && (DDL_2 = str2.value) User will be notifyied

Comment: Meaning that I need to check from DDL2 the values in DDL_1

Comment: either way i think your problem can be found in one or both of two places. the onselectedindexchange of 2nd ddl as well as in the page load methods

Comment: i think i get what you have to do i'll work on an example and replace my answer with it when i am done

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: there is my solution just place values in ddls when not post back. make sure to use two separate strings. for what you want to to do perform the code in  on index change again but instead of sender use dropdown list 1. then compare both strings to check your answer.